# Merging keywords through textareas

Tags: php

I've tried to create a short script, which takes values from 3 textboxes, and combine them together. However, it seems that I'm unable to populate the results into the textbox.

Here's the PHP function that I used to get the data from the textboxes and put them into arrays.

```
function get_text() {

    $text = trim($_POST['one']);
    $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
    $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

    $text2 = trim($_POST['two']);
    $textAr2 = explode("\n", $text2);
    $textAr2 = array_filter($textAr2, 'trim');

    $text3 = trim($_POST['three']);
    $textAr3 = explode("\n", $text3);
    $textAr3 = array_filter($textAr3, 'trim');
}
```

Here's the code that I used to create the tables, and also populate the "result" textarea with the results.

```
if(isset($_POST['done'])) {
            get_text();
            for($i=0; $i < count($textAr); $i++)
                for($j; $j < count($textAr2); $j++)
                    for ($k; $k < count($textAr3); $k++)
                    echo($textAr[i] + $textAr2[j] + $textAr3[k]);
        }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What output do you get.? Is there any error.?

Comment: why not just concate them using `.`

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 There is no output at all.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Regardless, there shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: no you can write the way you want its up to your logic how you want to implement the code, however your function is't returning anything so u need to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function doesn't return anything

```
function get_text() {

    $text = trim($_POST['one']);
    $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
    $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

    $text2 = trim($_POST['two']);
    $textAr2 = explode("\n", $text2);
    $textAr2 = array_filter($textAr2, 'trim');

    $text3 = trim($_POST['three']);
    $textAr3 = explode("\n", $text3);
    $textAr3 = array_filter($textAr3, 'trim');

    return array($textAr, $textAr2, $textAr3);
}
```

In above function I've added returning modified arrays. And in below statement I've added using result from get_gext function

```
if(isset($_POST['done'])) {
            list($textAr, $textAr2, $textAr3) = get_text();
          for($i=0; $i < count($textAr); $i++)
            for($j=0; $j < count($textAr2); $j++)
                for ($k=0; $k < count($textAr3); $k++)
                echo($textAr[$i] + $textAr2[$j] + $textAr3[$k]);
        }
```

Below the whole working code with sample data:

```
<?php


$_POST['done'] = true;

$_POST['one'] = "1\n2\n3";
$_POST['two'] = "1\n2\n3";
$_POST['three'] = "1\n2\n3";

function get_text() {

    $text = trim($_POST['one']);
    $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
    $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

    $text2 = trim($_POST['two']);
    $textAr2 = explode("\n", $text2);
    $textAr2 = array_filter($textAr2, 'trim');

    $text3 = trim($_POST['three']);
    $textAr3 = explode("\n", $text3);
    $textAr3 = array_filter($textAr3, 'trim');

    return array($textAr, $textAr2, $textAr3);
}



if(isset($_POST['done'])) {

            list($textAr, $textAr2, $textAr3) = get_text();


            for($i=0; $i < count($textAr); $i++)
                for($j=0; $j < count($textAr2); $j++)
                    for ($k=0; $k < count($textAr3); $k++)
                    echo($textAr[$i] + $textAr2[$j] + $textAr3[$k]);
        }
```

Comment: Despite returning the arrays, I am still not getting the results.

Comment: I've updated the for loops. You haven't initialized j and k variables, and in echo instead of $textAr[$i] you used $textAr[i]

Comment: Thanks for the continuous help. I've tried implementing the changes, and it's returning "0" now. Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Probably, you have some problem with sending post data. I've just edited answer and added the whole working code. So if post data are correct, calculation are made and everything works fine. If you have problem with sending post data you have to close this question and create another question with showing your form and your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help. There seems to be a problem sending post data. I will be creating another post showing the entire code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function get_text() {

    $text = trim($_POST['one']);
    $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
    $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

    $text2 = trim($_POST['two']);
    $textAr2 = explode("\n", $text2);
    $textAr2 = array_filter($textAr2, 'trim');

    $text3 = trim($_POST['three']);
    $textAr3 = explode("\n", $text3);
    $textAr3 = array_filter($textAr3, 'trim');

    $allAr = array_merge($textAr, $textAr2, $textAr3);
    return implode(" ", $allAr);
}

echo get_text();
```